# On a WPF ComboBox, is it possible to set a different Foreground color for the textbox and the popup?

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

Basically my problem stems from a desire to have the textbox portion be white, and the drop down to be black. When I set the text to white, the drop down appears as I want it, but the text in the textbox itself is hardly readable. Setting the Foreground to black makes the drop down unreadable.

Is there a good way to handle this? I am still learning WPF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the ControlTemplate, You will see a TextBlock and another PopUp which again has a set of controls. Have a different ForeGround/Background for this TextBox,

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to edit a copy of the template of the ComboBox and set the two of them independently.